Powerapps People Picker Combobox control does not display display names more than two if selected
I have canvas app that has 3 column layout.One of the field is a people picker field an dit is behaving as below.
When user selects 2 people then then it properly displays the display names delimited by comma.
When user selcts 3 people where the people display names are a bit samll , it again adjusts to display the names properly.
But, when user selects 3 person (display names are a bit bigger) or more than 3 person , the the field display the number of itesm selected that means it displays as 3 items, 4 items like this instead of names.
I tried below.
As this is a 3 column layout, I tried increasing the height if selcted person count>2. I though it will wrap the texts and adjust to display in next line. but it did not worked.
Kindly help and suggest is their any wayto resove this.
Thanks in advacnce.
